# How to make marker annotations in Eclipse extend to the whole width of the editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a plugin for the Eclipse IDE that adds a custom marker annotation to highlight portions of the code. Currently, I use textStylePreferenceValue="BOX" in the org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification and get a changed background color that ends at the line-break for each line. That introduces a lot of visual noise, and I would like to have the color to extend to the whole width of the editor. How can I achieve this?

If this is not possible at the moment, what would be the next steps to add this functionality to the platform?

This is what I have:
[image: Current appearance of the marker]

This is what I want:
[image: Intended appearance of the marker]

Answer (score 0):

After researching further, it seems that this is not possible at the moment, at least not easily. The relevant Eclipse sub-project seems to be "platform.text" (https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/). The possible textStylePreferenceValues are defined in the class "org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AnnotationPreference", and how to paint them is defined in the class "org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationPainter".

A low level solution could be to use a LineBackgroundListener together with the StyledText object of the editor.